# Is there a way to add a lot of rows that have a pattern fast in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to add like 200 rows(or something) with the values I want in mysql?

There is a pattern in the values. Like so:

```
|maincolumn|column1|column2|column3|column4|
|page1     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page2     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page3     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
...
|page7     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 0     |
```

So basically 7 rows with 4 columns have to get a 1 or 0. And all the combinations should be put in the table. So the 7 rows together are 1 combination.

Then the next combination should be like:

```
|maincolumn|column1|column2|column3|column4|
|page1     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page2     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page3     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
...
|page7     | 1     | 1     | 0     | 1     |
```

but a combination should also be like:

```
|maincolumn|column1|column2|column3|column4|
|page1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page2     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page3     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
...
|page7     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 0     |
```

and

```
|maincolumn|column1|column2|column3|column4|
|page1     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page2     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
|page3     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
...
|page7     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
```

I need to add all the available combinations to mysql and as you can see, it's going to be alot of rows. Is there a way to add the rows in a faster way than just adding each row seperate? Especially for these kind of tables cause there's a pattern in it.

My php function right now:

```
$group=1;
$page=1;
$id=1;

for ($i = 0; $i< 392; $i++){
    DB::table('table')->insert(array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'group'=>$group,
    'page'=>$page,
   //'create'=>$create,
   //'read'=>$read,
   //'update'=>$update,
   //'delete'=>$delete
    ));

    $id++;
    $page++;
    if($page%8==0){
        $group++;
        $page=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would write mysql procedure to generate all combinations. Then you would not need to transfer data to mysql.

Comment: Somewhere, you'll have to write code. Whether it's in an SQL stored proc or app code or whatever. Pick the language you find easiest to work with and code it up. It seems the only problem you are facing with your cide is that you haven't written any yet.

Comment: @Bohemian I was thinking of using code as well but I have no idea how to get this pattern in it.

Comment: @Bohemian I know I need a **for** with $i<196(7*7*4) and then insert `'page'.$i` but I have no idea what to do with the pattern of the other columns

Answer (score 0):

As it appears to be binary, why don't you write a function that does the binary calculating and then store each single number as a separate column in the database via a for loop? If you use [decbin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) function, you could use the `$i` counter for the numbers as well. Then convert it to a string, count the length and then take it apart. The missing parts are filled with zeros.

Comment: Sorry I dont get this exactly man. Look at my edit. This is what my function looks like right now.